# como forçar uma caixa de dialogo ficar acima da outra?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho 1 caixa de dialogo que chama uma 2, só que essa 2 precisa ficar acima da 1
como forço isso via javascript? ou qualquer outra forma, menos z-index que tentei e não tá indo.

Comment: o estilo z-ndex só funciona no objeto que já existe uma position previamente definida. Tente definir position para suas caixas de dialogo e aplique o z-index.

Comment: @BrunoCastro eu já fiz isso. eu já usei exatamente esse código em outro trecho e funciona perfeitamente, mas quando repito esse mesmo trecho em outra parte ele não funciona. Tem algum js que posso forçar?

Comment: Então, por favor, edite sua pergunta e adicione o código que você tentou fazer. Atente-se também em gerar um [mcve].

Comment: Coloca mais coisas para podermos te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não postou algum código ou algo do tipo fiz um exemplo com divs , se meu exemplo não servi edite a pergunta, e comente abaixo para que eu possa modificar podendo assim te ajudar melhor.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#mostrarDiv').click(function(){
    $('.div2').show(250);
  });
  $('#ocultarDiv').click(function(){
    $('.div2').hide(250);
  });
});
```

```css
.div1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.div2{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30;
  left: 30;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#mostrarDiv{
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
}

#ocultarDiv{
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" id="mostrarDiv" value="Chamar div 2">
<input type="button" id="ocultarDiv" value="Ocultar div 2">
```